# SwiftUI onDelete cannot detect tap when onTapGesture is added

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am developing an iOS app with list by SwiftUI. I am implementing .onDelete to enable user to delete the rows. However, I have found that when I add a .onTapGesture to the VStack View containing the List, the onDelete function is not called when the user tapped the "Delete" button after slide the row left. However, it stills works when the user slide the row to the left side to delete this. It seems that the .onTapGesture blocks .onDelete to receive user input. How to solve this?

```
NavigationView {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        List {
            ForEach(things) { thing in
                Text(thing)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                things.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
            })
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        }
    .onTapGesture {
    }
}
```

Here is some code that can show my problem.

Comment: strange that there isn't a straight forward solution to this, such a common thing in iOS app

Comment: I'm having the same issue and it's 2023. Does anyone know the legit solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably useless and very hacky but... If you must have an area that is tappable, you could place everything in a ZStack and put a random view over the List and make that tappable. Then you could set a good amount of padding to free the area where the delete button would be tapped, like this:

```
        NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            List {
                ForEach(things, id: \.self) { thing in
                    Text(thing)
                    }
                        .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                            things.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                        })
                    }
                        .zIndex(2)
                        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            
                Rectangle()
                    .zIndex(3)
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .padding(.trailing, 80)
                    .allowsHitTesting(true)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("Blocking you")
                    }
                }
        }
```

I put the color in so you can see exactly where you are working, the code above would give you a look like this:

[Tappable Rectangle on List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhAsz.png)

When you're happy with the area that the rectangle covers, you can just set the Opacity to a very small amount, just by replacing the color with

```
.opacity(0.000001)
```

or something. Unfortunately taps don't work with Color.clear or hidden() modifiers.

Comment: Actually I add the onTapGesture to disable a keyboard that is active, so the tappable area should be the whole screen. All other buttons in the view that has been added onTapGesture work well except the delete button.

Comment: @CollinZhang I have the same use case, I need the entire parent to be clickable to dismiss the keyboard, but it prevents the delete button from being tappable. Did you ever figure this out?